# Android Studio AlarmManager Background Repeat Run

Tags: android, android-intent, service, timer, background

I am attempting to create a background Service so when the application is closed a service is running in the background that will show a notification every 5 seconds to the phone using an AlarmManager.

I currently have my java service file setup as:

```
package com.racecoursedatatechnologies.rdtstockmanagement;

import android.app.Service;
import android.app.AlarmManager;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Log;
import android.os.Binder;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.app.PendingIntent;

public class BackIntentService extends Service {

    private PendingIntent pendingIntent;
    private AlarmManager manager;

    public class LocalBinder extends Binder {
        BackIntentService getService() {
            return BackIntentService.this;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        startAlarm();
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Log.d("LocalService", "Received start id " + startId + ": " + intent);
        return START_NOT_STICKY;
    }

    public void startAlarm()
    {
        manager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(this.ALARM_SERVICE);
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, BackNotifyAlarm.class);
        pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intent, 0);

        int interval = 1000 * 5;

        manager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(), interval, pendingIntent);
        Toast.makeText(this, "Alarm Started", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {

        // Tell the user we stopped.
        Log.d("LocalService", "Stopped");
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return mBinder;
    }

    // This is the object that receives interactions from clients.  See
    // RemoteService for a more complete example.
    private final IBinder mBinder = new LocalBinder();

    /**
     * Show a notification while this service is running.
     */
    private void showNotification() {

        //Create a notification and set it's content and display it.
        NotificationManager notif=(NotificationManager)getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        Notification notify=new Notification.Builder
                (getApplicationContext()).setContentTitle("RDT Stock").setContentText("HELLOOO").
                setContentTitle("Low Stock Items").setSmallIcon(R.drawable.noticon).build();

        notify.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
        notif.notify(11, notify);
    }

}
```

BackNotifyAlarm Broadcast java file:

```
public class BackNotifyAlarm extends BroadcastReceiver
{
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        //PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) context.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
        //PowerManager.WakeLock wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "");
        //wl.acquire();

        Toast.makeText(context, "Notification sent!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        //wl.release();

    }
```

I am starting the service in the `MainActivity` file. The service starts and the service then runs an Alarm, however the alarm only seems to run once and not repeat, any idea why?

Comment: What you want is not really possible on Android 6.0+. The closest solutions are to use `AlarmManager` (perhaps paired with your `Service`) or `JobScheduler` (on Android 5.0+). Do **not** attempt to have your service run continuously, just to watch the clock tick.

Comment: I have updated the main code with the AlarmManager in. It works however for some reason its not running every 5 seconds it seems to take alot longer.

Comment: You cannot do alarms that quickly. On Android 5.1+, the minimum period is one minute, and it will be a lot less frequent in Doze mode on Android 6.0+.

Comment: Cheers. I sorted it now by using a thread instead.